# How to separate domain model from REST module?

Tags: java, module, architecture, domain-driven-design

I have a multi-module Java application in DDD, which among others includes web (REST) module with mappers, which has a dependency to domain module which takes care of business logic.

Mapping from domain objects to DTOs is made in web module, but I don't want it to have knowledge about entities and value objects from domain model.

I was thinking about introducing a new module for creating separation  between web and domain. It would receive calls from web and transfer them to domain (business layer) but this solution needs a lot of mappers and new objects which in my opinion a bit obfuscate the application as it is going to have about 50 classes.

Are there any other approaches to this problem or it is not that severe as I think and can stay as it is currently.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your questions is not very clear. Can you share more details?

Comment: You would usually have REST -> ApplicationLayer -> Domain/Infrastructure

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The job you are describing is done by the application layer of DDD, no need to add another module. Application layer maps domain objects to dtos and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm still a bit confused because my technical lead claims application layer should not return dtos, he thinks that it's responsibility of web layer (in my case holding rest controllers etc) - is he wrong? I encountered few posts telling that application layer should return dtos, but because of his opinion I'm still in doubt.

Comment: Well I don't agree with him then. DTOs are the args/return types of application services. An application service builds domain objects from DTOs and viceversa, to decouple domain from clients (eg controllers). You can take a look too the red book "Implementing DDD" by Vaughn Vernon, or to the github repo of book code samples (https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/tree/master). Take a look to the application layer of the collaboration context. Another example: the command pattern... it is applied in the application layer. Command handlers are application services and commands are DTOs

Comment: @devoxy anyway I'm not saying that he is wrong and I'm right. I am just saying that I don't agree with him. I think DTOs belong to application layer, that's what I do in my projects. I do so because after reading "Implementing DDD" book that's what I understand.

Comment: @devoxy In chapter 14 (application) of the book, the "user interface" section (page 512) explains some different ways of how application layer can deal with providing info to clients without exposing the domain. One of such alternatives is DTOs:  

- dtos  
- mediator  
- domain payload objects  
- state representations  
- use case optimal repository queries (closed to cqrs)  
- data transformers

Comment: Thank you @choquero70. Your reply helped me a lot. After reading stackoverflow for past 2 days to find answers for this and other questions I think the same. Application layer should be used here and it should be used with DTOs.

Comment: @choquero70 "Application layer maps domain objects to dtos" - well, it mostly coordinates calls to the domain and infrastructure. Whether this has to involve DTO's and, even more so, mapping them to domain objects is highly debatable.

Comment: @guillaume31 well it's my fault, application layer itself doesn't do the mapping, but it calls the mappers that do the mapping. And of course I said those things assuming he is using DTOs (he says so in the question). In that case, I think the mapping is done in the application layer, not in the web module neither another module you have too add for it. At least that's my understanding after reading Implementing DDD by Vaughn Vernon. Of course I may be wrong, but that's how I do it. Regards.

Comment: @guillaume31 applying command pattern in the application layer is an example of what i'm saying too. A command is a dto in the end. And a command handler is an application service. Another example is the application services of the collaboration context of Vaughn Vernon sorce code from his book IDDD. Of course you don't have to use dtos, but if you do, application layer construct domain object from them and viceversa, as application layer is the direct client of domain model. That way application layer doesn't expose domain to clients. Regards

Comment: @choquero70 I know what you mean, but "mapping domain objects to dtos and vice versa" suggests that there's a 1-1 correspondence between their fields. It might be the case in more anemic domains, less so in richer contexts or with CQRS where commands capture user intent.

Comment: @guillaume31 yeah of course, you are right, my fault again using wrong english word. I should have said converting or translating , that's what i meant . Not mapping. Sorry